# cmake build error, files doesn't seem to exist

Tags: ubuntu, sdk, cmake, qml, ubuntu-15.04

I'm working with ubuntu-sdk on ubuntu-15.04.

I created a qml project with cmake and 3 kits:

- Desktop
- UbuntuSDK_for_armhf_GCC_ubuntu_sdk_15_04
- UbuntuSDK_for_i386_GCC_ubuntu_sdk_15_04

When I try to run the default app on my ubuntu phone. There is a built-problem occurring.

**This is the ouput:**

```
Makefile:295: recipe for target 'cmake_check_build_system' failed
CMake Error at /var/lib/schroot/chroots/click-ubuntu-sdk-15.04-armhf/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/cmake/Qt5Core/Qt5CoreConfig.cmake:27 (message):
  The imported target "Qt5::Core" references the file

     "/var/lib/schroot/chroots/click-ubuntu-sdk-15.04-armhf/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/bin/moc"
```

But this file does not exist.  Possible reasons include:

- The file was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.
- An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.
- The installation package was faulty and contained `"/var/lib/schroot/chroots/click-ubuntu-sdk-15.04-armhf/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/cmake/Qt5Core/Qt5CoreConfigExtras.cmake"`

But not all the files it references.

```
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /var/lib/schroot/chroots/click-ubuntu-sdk-15.04-armhf/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/cmake/Qt5Core/Qt5CoreConfigExtras.cmake:17 (_qt5_Core_check_file_exists)
  /var/lib/schroot/chroots/click-ubuntu-sdk-15.04-armhf/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/cmake/Qt5Core/Qt5CoreConfig.cmake:158 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)
```

What could I do to fix the error? 
Thanks for all the answers coming up.

Answer (score 0):

It's from the `qtbase5-dev-tools` package. Make sure that it's installed inside that chroot.

Go to something like options -> manage to get into a command line of that toolkit.

Comment: hey thanks a lot for the answer. The kit is installed in:"/var/lib/schroot/chroots/click-ubuntu-sdk-15.04-armhf"
When i change in to the kit. I'm getting in to the root of the kit. Where should i install this package in the kit? And how should i do this?

Comment: It's just like an Ubuntu VM. So, as usual: `apt-get install qtbase5-dev-tools`.

Comment: Yeah but the terminal still belongs to my system and not to the kit. I wasn't able to open a terminal just for the kit.

Comment: It belongs to the main OS? It said that in some kind of error message?